# Accessing fields filter parameters in IResourceService in JsonApiDotNetCore

Tags: c#, json, rest, .net-core, json-api

I am currently trying to set up a Non-Entity Framework environment to access data via REST/[JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) in ASP.NET Core 3.1  with https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore

I followed the example as shown in: https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/master/src/Examples/NoEntityFrameworkExample/Services/WorkItemService.cs

So here is my sample method:

```
public class DepartmentResourceService : IResourceService<Department>
{

    public Task<IReadOnlyCollection<Department>> GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<Department> departments = new List<Department>{
            new Department{ Id = 1, Name = "SE", Contact = "se@someaddress.at" },
            new Department{ Id = 2, Name = "SD", Contact = "sd@someaddress.at" }
        }.AsReadOnly();
        return Task.FromResult(departments);
    }

...

}
```

My example works pretty well, but I haven't figured out how I can access the given JSON:API [fields-filter](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-fields).
However: The filters do apply automatically somehow and only the given fields are sent which were defined in the query string, but the filter is applied *after* the object was generated.
When using EF, I can see that the sql-queries are already limited to the defined JSON:API [fields-filter](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-fields) list, therefore the object is only filled up with informationen that was requested and nothing else.

I would like to do the same without EF, but I am missing that filter information in order to do so.

I could figure out, that there is an Interface called `ITargetedFields` (https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/master/src/JsonApiDotNetCore/Resources/TargetedFields.cs/) and I thought maybe this could be injected into the constructor like so:

```
public class DepartmentResourceService : IResourceService<Department>
{
    private readonly ITargetedFields targetedFields;

    public DepartmentResourceService(ITargetedFields targetedFields)
    {
        this.targetedFields = targetedFields;
    }
...
}
```

But the properties `Attributes` and `Relationships` Collections of `ITargetedFields` are always zero-length.

I couldn't find something in the docs or examples.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way, how to access query information, such as fields, pagination, includes in `IResourceService<TResource>`:

There are several [`IQueryConstraintProvider`](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/master/src/JsonApiDotNetCore/Queries/IQueryConstraintProvider.cs) service providers registered in [`JsonApiApplicationBuilder`](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/master/src/JsonApiDotNetCore/Configuration/JsonApiApplicationBuilder.cs) in the method `AddQueryStringLayer()` with a Scope-Lifetime:

- `IIncludeQueryStringParameterReader`
- `IFilterQueryStringParameterReader`
- `ISortQueryStringParameterReader`
- `ISparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader`
- `IPaginationQueryStringParameterReader`
- `IResourceDefinitionQueryableParameterReader`

They are injected by DI in the constructor of your `IResourceService<TResource>` implementation, here is an example:

```
public class DepartmentResourceService : IResourceService<Department>
{
    private readonly ISparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader _sparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader;
    private readonly IIncludeQueryStringParameterReader _includeQueryStringParameterReader;
    private readonly ISortQueryStringParameterReader _sortQueryStringParameterReader;
    private readonly IPaginationQueryStringParameterReader _paginationQueryStringParameterReader;

    public DepartmentResourceService(
        ISparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader sparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader,
        IIncludeQueryStringParameterReader includeQueryStringParameterReader,
        ISortQueryStringParameterReader sortQueryStringParameterReader,
        IPaginationQueryStringParameterReader paginationQueryStringParameterReader
        )
    {
        _sparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader = sparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader;
        _includeQueryStringParameterReader = includeQueryStringParameterReader;
        _sortQueryStringParameterReader = sortQueryStringParameterReader;
        _paginationQueryStringParameterReader = paginationQueryStringParameterReader;
    }
    public Task<IReadOnlyCollection<Department>> GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        // Accessing all provided information:
        IReadOnlyCollection<ExpressionInScope> constraints = _sparseFieldSetQueryStringParameterReader.GetConstraints();
        IReadOnlyCollection<ExpressionInScope> includes = _includeQueryStringParameterReader.GetConstraints();
        IReadOnlyCollection<ExpressionInScope> sortQuery = _sortQueryStringParameterReader.GetConstraints();
        IReadOnlyCollection<ExpressionInScope> pagination = _paginationQueryStringParameterReader.GetConstraints();

        // ***************************************************************
        // Do what ever you need to do, with the information provided here
        // ***************************************************************

        // Return something
        IReadOnlyCollection<Department> departments = new List<Department>{
            new Department{ Id = 1, Name = "SE", Contact = "se@someaddress.at" },
            new Department{ Id = 2, Name = "SD", Contact = "sd@someaddress.at" }
        }.AsReadOnly();
        return Task.FromResult(departments);
    }
...
}
```